# Wrapping view inside NavigationLink overrides text alignment of Text in view to centered

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I created a custom menu consisting of Views in a Scrollview.

```
struct MenuInformationDetailView: View {
var title: String = "title"
var subTitle: String = "subTitle"
var imageName: String = "exclamationmark.circle.fill"

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Image(systemName: imageName)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .accessibility(hidden: true)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .accessibility(addTraits: .isHeader)

            Text(subTitle)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.8)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
    .padding(.top)
}
}
```

Then I wrap the view in a NavigationLink to go to the desired destination:

```
NavigationLink(destination: PanicDiaryEducationView()) {
        InformationDetailView(title: "Changing behaviour", subTitle: "How to use the behavioural experiments feature", imageName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
                       }
```

For some reason, doing this causes the Subtitle text (and probably title) to be Centered rather than the default leading alignment. using `.frame(alignment : .topLeading)` doesn't change it.

When not wrapped in the `NavigationLink` It formats correctly.

How can I stop it from centering the Text?

[image: Centered]
[image: Correct]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is something about *default* multi-line text alignment. As with many *default* in SwiftUI it is very often not obvious. So it is better to make it explicit. So here is a fix:

```
Text(subTitle)
    .font(.body)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)   // << here !!
```

Comment: This is really infuriating. These defaults are infuriating. From the VStack/HStack default magical spacings that you have to workaround, to this weird and super annoying behavior of the NavigationLink. Why would an innocent NavigationLink recursively override children style properties? Wasn't like this in SwiftUI1. Developer could easily use a view modifier for this unnecessary default behavior.